# Responding to Shell prompt from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: bash, shell, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When using the `!` shortcut to execute shell commands from a Notebook, how can I respond to subsequent prompts?

For example: `!read varname` Seems to hang the kernel indefinitely and I can't run another command to respond.

Anticipating the prompt in one cell like this doesn't work either:

```
!read varname
!my_answer
!echo $varname
```

The cell hangs with [*]

(these are simplified examples, the actual use case needs to respond to a 'y/n' prompt)

Comment: Don't think it's possible, check https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/514. You can still use `-y` or `-n` option explicitly in the command.

Comment: Thank you! The ```-y``` option works for my use case, which is uninstalling a package: ```!pip uninstall openpyxl -y```. I'll leave this question open since this is not a solution to the question as posted.

Answer (score 1):

The input stream of the temporary bash subshell is not connected to your browser.
Sending a command to the jupyter kernel is one-way -- there is no interaction. The bash is no exception here.

State changes -- like changing the working directory with a 'cd' command -- require special implementation effort: 'magic commands'.